# SQL Multiplying result of subquery with other

Tags: sql, sum

As you can see by the title, I cannot really phrase what I want to do. Basically I have 2 tables:

```
--offers--
offer_id varchar 
offer_price int

--carts--
user_name varchar 
offer_id varchar
offer_count int
```

Now I want to get the total price of all the items in the shopping basket (cart). I've come this far:

```
select sum(offer_price) from offers where offer_id IN 
(
    select offer_id from carts where user_name='root'
);
```

However that approach completely ignores the offer_count value of the shopping basket. How would I implement that? (I'm relatively unexperienced in SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the tables:

```
select
    sum(c.offer_count *  o.offer_price) total
from carts c
    join offers o
on c.offer_id = c.offer_id
where c.user_name = 'root'
```

Comment: You might add a little explanation so he understands what you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks alot! Though you made a little typo. It should be "on c.offer_id = o.offer_id", just incase someone has the same question ;-)